# How can I add a source address to google map intent from activity using "google.navigation:ll"?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I want to add a **source address** in `google.navigation:ll`. When I am using this it is showing navigation from the `current location` to the set **destination**. How do I add a parameter for `source address`?

This is my current code line:

```
double latitudeDestination = 22.5834881; // or some other location
double longitudeDestination = 88.3078827; // or some other location
String requestedMode = "car"; // or bike or car
String mode = "";
if(requestedMode.equals("walking")) {
   mode = "&mode=w";
 } else if(requestedMode.equals("bike")) {
   mode = "&mode=b";
 } else if(requestedMode.equals("car")) {
   mode = "&mode=c";
 }

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(String.format("google.navigation:ll=%s,%s%s,
                latitudeDestination, longitudeDestination, mode)));
startActivity(intent);
```

Note: I have followed [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents) .

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get direction and routes you can use the [Web Service of Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview). The Google Maps web services are a collection of HTTP interfaces to Google services providing geographic data for your maps applications. These web services use HTTP requests to specific URLs, passing URL parameters as arguments to the services. It will provide you everything. I have used this in my application.

Here is the example where `saddr = source address & daddr= destination address`. You can also pass string as address instead of lat/lng.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+ latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No I want to launch **google.navigation** directly from my app on button click. The solution you have provided opens google map route from A to B. I don't want this.